# How to align text with ul & li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have **4 Div** with class **col-md-3** in one row
but the text does appear really ugly. i have made an little overview here:

```
 Prod.      Comp.    (middle)    lang.     div4
   text     texttext              text     text
 textta       text                 txt      txt
```

this means, the text is not under the  /Product, company, languange, and the 4th Division

i want to have it look like this

```
 div1      div2     (middle)    div3     div4
 text      texttext             text     text
 textta    text                 txt      txt
```

here is my code

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row" id="footerRow">

                 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <h2>Product</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="templates.php">Templates</a></li> 
                        <li> <a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <h2>Company</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="terms.php">Terms of Servise</a></li>
                            <li><a href="policy.php">Privacy policy</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <h2>Language</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="login.php">Englisch</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">German</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">Srpski</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>          

                 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                    <h2> </h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="login.php">facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>  

            </div>
        </div>
```

here is my css code:

```
#footerRow{
  text-align: center;
}
```

the solution should be responsive bootstrap if possible!

Comment: remove that property "text-align:center" from #footerRow div, or change it "center" to "left". i.e. "text-align:left".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `padding` and `margin` for zero. Remove `text-align:center` for `#footerRow`

```css
#footerRow ul {margin:0px;padding:0px}
#footerRow ul li{
  text-align: left;
  list-style:none
}
#footerRow h2{min-height:30px}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="footerRow">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <h2>Product</h2>
        <ul>
          <li> <a href="templates.php">Templates</a></li> 
          <li> <a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <h2>Company</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="terms.php">Terms of Servise</a></li>
          <li><a href="policy.php">Privacy policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <h2>Language</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="login.php">Englisch</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.php">German</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.php">Srpski</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>          
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <h2> </h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="login.php">facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
          <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change center to left

```
text-align: left
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text-align) are a few examples.

Answer (score 0):

see if this is what you'r looking for https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26745/

just remove

```
#footerRow{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this...

```css
ol, ul {list-style: none;}
#footerRow ul {margin:0px;padding:0px}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Stack Overflow</title>
 <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="footerRow">

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <h2>Product</h2>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="templates.php">Templates</a></li>
                <li> <a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <h2>Company</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="terms.php">Terms of Servise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="policy.php">Privacy policy</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <h2>Language</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Englisch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">German</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Srpski</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <h2> Div4</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="login.php">facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Venkatachalam_Perisetla/2k7b7hnh/)  Here [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/Venkatachalam_Perisetla/2k7b7hnh/)

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
#footerRow{
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="footerRow">

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <h2>Product</h2>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="templates.php">Templates</a></li> 
                <li> <a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <h2>Company</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="terms.php">Terms of Servise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="policy.php">Privacy policy</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <h2>Language</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Englisch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">German</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Srpski</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>          

         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
            <h2>Social </h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="login.php">facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>  

    </div>
</div>
```